# Android Browser in Windows

Tags: android, android-emulator, webkit

Is there a way to install the Android SDK Web Browser's web kit engine in widows and customize it to Run in your windows environment directly ?

So that we dont need to depend upon the Emulator/ device to check how your Web page works in it - which would be simpler and faster

Answer (score 7):

You can emulate some Android browser features in Google Chrome. Type *Ctrl-Shift-I* to open Chrome Developer Tools, click *Settings* - the gear icon in bottom right corner, click *Overrides* on the left, then check *User Agent* and select *Android 4.0.2* below, next check *Device Metrics* and *Emulate touch events*. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation).

Alternatively, you can install [Windroy](http://www.socketeq.com) - a full port of Android to Windows.

Comment: Tried Windroy from here http://www.techspot.com/downloads/6124-windroy.html. Works good

Comment: This answer needs to be updated. Now just can just press f12, then click the little mobile phone icon in top left.

Answer (score 3):

Now on Chrome (at the time of version 53), Device Mode allows to get you close to the real device behaviour (yet not emulating it fully). To launch it:

- type Ctrl-Shift-I to open Chrome Developer Tools,
- then type Ctrl-Shift-M to toggle in device mode,
- a toolbar appears on top of your page with a dropdown menu from which you can emulate different mobile browsers (default option of the menu is "Responsive").

This list of available devices can be augmented in the Developer Tools settings > Devices.

Comment: But still its not the same as the chrome browser of the android os, is it ?

Comment: No, it's not. As Paul Bakaus stated in this article (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/), Device Mode is "a close approximation", and test on real devices should still be performed. Yet it's still a handy and convenient way to get rid of many compatibility issues before real-device testing. I'll edit my post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I've found until now, it's to connect my mobile device with [Chrome's Remote Devices feature](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging)

[image: Chrome Remote Device]

---

1. Open the Developer Options screen on your Android.
2. Select Enable USB Debugging.
3. On your development machine, open Chrome.
4. Open DevTools.
5. In DevTools, click the Main Menu Main Menu then select More tools > Remote devices.
6. You need to have Chrome open in your Mobile Device, you will see a list with all opened tabs

---

This is awesome, because, not only you can browse your mobile's tabs directly in your Machine, but you can normally debug your app, like you are debugging on Chrome Desktop (Elements, Console, Sources, Network, Performance, Application, Security, etc).
Check remote debugging troubleshooting section [over here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging#troubleshooting)

Comment: This is awesome. However looks like it's moved from the "More tools" menu and can now be found by going to chrome://inspect/#devices

Answer (score -1):

I dont think that is possible as the browser is built to run on the Android stack.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but seems lie we could build our own webkit as provided in the link below [link](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Chromium)